# Micro integrator - RabbitMQ workflow

Tags: rabbitmq, wso2, wso2-micro-integrator

I'm looking into integration of WSO2 MI and RabbitMQ, the goal is to create a system with the following steps:
1. MI receive request from a client and send the message to RabbitMQ
2. RabbitMQ put message in the queue and it's taken by the subscriber client for processing.
3. Message with response from the processing service placed into response RabbitMQ queue.
4. MI receive message from that response queue and send reply to the client.

There is following documentation in wso2 official manuals:
https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/setup/brokers/configure-with-rabbitMQ/
https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/use-cases/examples/jms_examples/rabbitmq-examples/

I assume that's what I need, but it's not clear how exactly these should be executed.

Let's say I've configured a connection to RabbitMQ in MI.

How exactly do I use these `synapse configurations` mentioned in the docs to be able to send messages to rabbit based on the client request or reply to a client based on messages from rabbit?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple patterns for synchronous/asynchronous messaging with RabbitMQ in WSO2 Enterprise Integrator. Please have a look at these examples.

- [Point to Point](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/use-cases/examples/rabbitmq_examples/point-to-point-rabbitmq/)
- [Publisher/Subscriber](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/use-cases/examples/rabbitmq_examples/pub-sub-rabbitmq/)
- [Guaranteed Delivery](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/use-cases/examples/rabbitmq_examples/store-forward-rabbitmq/)
- [Request/Response - Dual Channel](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/use-cases/examples/rabbitmq_examples/request-response-rabbitmq/)

Furthermore, you can find a tutorial for the asynchronous messaging from [here](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/use-cases/tutorials/storing-and-forwarding-messages/)!